# How to get NSString value from NSPopupButton dropdown list?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenuitem

Get username  values from sqlite db.

```
-(NSArray*)getUname
{ 

NSArray *resul = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 NSArray *fetchedRecords = [resul valueForKey:@"uName"];
}
```

Insert this array values into NSPopupButton

```
[_registeredUserPopupButton addItemsWithTitles:[self getUname]];
```

Get a string value from NSPopupButton dropdown list

```
NSString *usrNam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_registeredUserPopupButton selectedItem]];
```

From the above code usrNam value returns like below

"NSMenuItem: 0x6080000a9c00 mickel"

but i want my nsstring output as "mickel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `title` from the menu item:

```
NSString *usrNam = [[_registeredUserPopupButton selectedItem] title];
```

or with dot notation

```
NSString *usrNam = _registeredUserPopupButton.selectedItem.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

The -selectedItem method returns a NSMenuItem object. This in turn has a title property which is what I think you are looking for. Should be as below I think.

```
NSString *usrNam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_registeredUserPopupButton selectedItem.title]];
```